# How can I add a free form text field to the contact details page

Tags: contact, notes

I'd like to have a text field maybe 80x8 characters on the Contacts page just to make quick notes without having to go to the related tab and create a note.  Do other people have this need, and if so, how did they solve it?  Just by adding a custom field to the Contacts object and moving it onto the page layout - or is there a better way?

Comment: Does it matter if the notes might be visible for other users? Is chatter an option?

Comment: I'm an Essentials user, so it's just me!  The point was to just make it easy and effortless to add quick comments about the contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of ways we can do this with the current technology available to us. We could create a custom field (as you thought) and use a trigger/flow to copy the text to a note, you could write a Visualforce page and drop it inline, allowing for a freeform text area that can immediately save a new note without having to go inline edit, for Lightning we can create a component and add it to the page to allow the ability to quick-add a note, post stuff via Chatter, etc.

The main points you need to consider basically revolve around determining which contexts you want this available in. There's three basic things you need to consider: Classic UI, Lightning Experience (LEX), and API (SOAP, REST). The trigger/flow/Chatter route gives you access in all three, Visualforce gives you the ability in Classic and LEX, and Lightning Components can also be used in Classic and LEX, but will require slightly more code to accomplish.

I wouldn't necessarily say one way is "better" than others, it really depends on whatever suits your needs. There are variations that may be better for certain situations, but there's at least four viable options.

Comment: I tried Chatter and it was ok, but I thought I'd be better off creating a custom field of type Long Text Area, and that really seemed to fit the bill.